# Как сделать config файл, который будет изменяться по состоянию Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, config

Мне необходимо написать конфиг, с какими - то дефолтными значениями, по которым будет отображаться template. И в Redux у меня есть состояние, которое уже изменяет template. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы то, что меняет Redux меняло файл конфигурации непосредственно при изменении Redux состояния.

Снизу просто пример:

`export const config = { mainColor: 'red', template: 'LeftBigSidebar' }`

Comment: Конфиг чего, конкретно?

Comment: Конфиг того, как будут отображаться элементы. Ну грубо говоря, как мне менять JSON файл в зависимости от внешних действий внутри JS - React, может Node;